# SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'pma_table_uiprefs'

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have got this error message in Vesta Control Panel, in phpMyAdmin:

> SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'pma_table_uiprefs'
>
> ```
> SELECT `prefs` 
> FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma_table_uiprefs` 
> WHERE `username` = 'admin_db1' 
> AND `db_name` = 'admin_db1' 
> AND `table_name` = 'testtable'
> ```

I have already tried to solve with this command:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON phpmyadmin.* 
TO 'admin_db1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if your `config.inc.php` has a properly configured controluser. The error message (indicating that permission was denied for user '') suggests some problem with your configuration file or the controluser itself.

Please look for the two controluser lines which should read as:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']   = 'admin_db1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']   = 'mypassword';
```

If they are there and correct, please try connecting as that account from the command line client (on the same machine running phpMyAdmin) to see if you can manually USE the `phpmyadmin` database and that the table `pma_table_uiprefs` exists.

If all that fails, you may wish to post your `config.inc.php` here, obscuring any sensitive information such as usernames, passwords, and hostnames.

Or, alternatively, if you have no need for the advanced configuration options you can just remove the controluser, controlpass, and pmadb lines from your `config.inc.php` and it will bypass that part completely.

Comment: Where can I find `config.inc.php`.file?

Comment: Normally it's in the main phpMyAdmin directory, though if you used a package manager or packaged kit to install it, they might have put it elsewhere.